# Ecto has_one without belongs_to in Phoenix

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto, elixir

I have a `Home` model which contains content for a home page such as `intro_copy`, `about_image` and `about_copy`.

On the `Home` model, I’d also like to be able to feature 3 posts from my `Post` model using `has_one` relationship. Basically just linking them using an id.

My `Home` schema looks like this:

```
schema "home" do
  field :intro_copy, :string
  field :about_copy, :string
  field :about_image, Image.Type

  has_one :post_1, Post
  has_one :post_2, Post
  has_one :post_3, Post

  timestamps()
end
```

My `changeset` function looks like this:

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast_assoc(params, [:post_1, :post_2, :post_3])
  |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
end
```

Also, in my migrations I have the following lines being added to the `:home` table:

```
add :post_1_id, references(:posts)
add :post_2_id, references(:posts)
add :post_3_id, references(:posts)
```

Is there somewhere I’m obviously going wrong here?

Comment: If the `homes` table contains references to `posts`, then `Home` should `belong_to` Post. `has_one` is for the reverse. Does `belongs_to` not work for you?

Comment: I’m not sure if I’ve done this the best way. I basically just want a way to be able to have 3 featured posts on the `Home` model. The `Home` model is a singleton too.

Comment: Yes, belongs_to is perfect for that. `has_*` relation is meant for when the other table has the references field. `belongs_to` is when the current table has the references field.

Comment: What should I change on my `home` schema above? I’m a bit confused about whether the `post_1`, `post_2` should still be in there.

Comment: Remove `has_one :post_1, Post` and add `belongs_to :post_1, Post` instead. This should work since the foreign key in the database is `:post_1_id`.

Comment: Great, I have it working! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `home` table contains references to `posts`, then `Home` should `belongs_to` `Post`. `has_one` is for the reverse -- you'd use it here if `posts` contained a field that referenced `home`.

If you change:

```
has_one :post_1, Post
has_one :post_2, Post
has_one :post_3, Post
```

to

```
belongs_to :post_1, Post
belongs_to :post_2, Post
belongs_to :post_3, Post
```

everything should work with the migration you've already written.